# How to add Bootstrap to Fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fullpage.js

I'm trying to add Bootstrap to Fullpage.js so in this way my site would be looked responsive. Basically I have got a simple layout for Fullpage.js which goes like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- This following line is optional. Only necessary if you use the option css3:false and you want to use other easing effects rather than "linear", "swing" or "easeInOutCubic". -->
        <script src="vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
        <!-- This following line is only necessary in the case of using the plugin option `scrollOverflow:true` -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                    sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2','#4BBFC3','#7BAABE','whitesmoke'],
                    css3: true
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .section{
            font-size:6em;
            text-align:center;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fullpage">
            <div class="section">Section 1</div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">Sction 2</div>
            <div class="section">Sction 3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I tried adding Bootstrap Jquery files and CSS files and called them...

**At the end of body section:**

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**At the head section:**

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

But whenever I do this the whole Fullpage.js would be crashed and no longer it works withing Bootstrap! So I don't know how to use Bootstrap with Fullpage.js, if you know how to do that please let me know ,I really appreciate that. ThX

Comment: you are using jquery two times, just use at once and it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code, it should work, just to make sure you use jquery plugin at once and organize it properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This following line is optional. Only necessary if you use the option css3:false and you want to use other easing effects rather than "linear", "swing" or "easeInOutCubic". -->
<script src="vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
<!-- This following line is only necessary in the case of using the plugin option `scrollOverflow:true` -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#fullpage').fullpage({
              sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2','#4BBFC3','#7BAABE','whitesmoke'],
              css3: true
          });
      });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 .section {
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullpage">
 <div class="section">Section 1</div>
 <div class="section">
 <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
 <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
 <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
<div class="section">Sction 2</div>
<div class="section">Sction 3</div>
</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I Have tried your way but still I am unable to get the desired result can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123792/unable-to-load-bootstrap-to-fullpage-js)?