# Unable to load bootstrap to fullpage js

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fullpage.js

Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873417/8919244) I have tried to add create a simple full-page with bootstrap.

I want my front end to be like fullpage scrolling so it will be responsive.

**Setup Folder**

[image]

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/jquery.fullPage.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This following line is optional. Only necessary if you use the option css3:false and you want to use other easing effects rather than "linear", "swing" or "easeInOutCubic". -->
<script src="vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
<!-- This following line is only necessary in the case of using the plugin option `scrollOverflow:true` -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
          sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2','#4BBFC3','#7BAABE','whitesmoke'],
          css3: true
      });
  });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
       .section {
font-size: 6em;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section">Section 1</div>
<div class="section">
<div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
<div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
<div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
<div class="section">Section 2</div>
<div class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

I am using `Sublime Text Editor 3` for designing the front end. I must be missing something and I am stuck to it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is your question or what is your expected output? Can you explain more

Comment: @UdhayTitusP I want to add bootstrap to fullpage.js like [this](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1)

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4 or older

Comment: @UdhayTitusP yes bootstrap 4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use all the external links proper, you may be missed some links, check it

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
          sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2','#4BBFC3','#7BAABE','whitesmoke'],
          css3: true
      });
  });
```

```css
  .section {
font-size: 6em;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.5/fullpage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.5/fullpage.js"></script>


<body>
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section">Section 1</div>
<div class="section">
<div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
<div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
<div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
<div class="section">Section 2</div>
<div class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[Check the jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/br0m8nxe/1/)